# RSA Signature Verification with No Certificate JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rsa, signature, verification, sha256

Sorry if this question is horribly formatted, this is the first time I've asked one on this site...

So, currently, I am working on a JavaScript extension for Chrome that is supposed to verify an RSA signature without using a certificate.  And I just cannot, for the life of me, figure out what is going wrong! I've looked for hours for some answers or alternative methods but couldn't find anything that worked specifically for my code.  Here is my code so far to clarify my issue:

Signature generating function

```
function sign(sk, m, certname) {

    var key = new RSAKey();

    key.setPrivate(sk.n, sk.e, sk.d);

    var h = CryptoJS.SHA256(JSON.stringify(m)).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);

    h = new BigInteger(h, 16);

    var sig = key.doPrivate(h).toString(16);

    var obj = { "type": "SIGNED", "msg": m, "certname": certname, "sig": sig };

    return JSON.stringify(obj);

}
```

Verification

```
function verify(pk, signed) {

var key = new RSAKey();
var s = JSON.stringify(signed.sig).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
s = parseInt(s, 16);
var e = JSON.stringify(pk.e).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
log(e);
var n = JSON.stringify(pk.n).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
log(n);
var v = Math.pow(s, e) % n;
var hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(signed.msg).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
log(v);
log(hash);
return (v == hash);

}
```

In the log, v is, for some reason, always has the value infinity.  Am I using the wrong technique?  Is there a way for my current function to be fixed or is it completely wrong?

Update:

I tried changing the code to:

```
function verify(pk, signed) {

var key = new RSAKey();
var s = JSON.stringify(signed.sig).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
s = new BigInteger(s, 16);
log("s:  " + s);
var e = JSON.stringify(pk.e).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
e = new BigInteger(e, 2);
log("e:  " + e);
var n = JSON.stringify(pk.n).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
n = new BigInteger(n, 16);
log("n:  " + n);
key.setPublic(n, e);
var v = key.doPublic(s).toString(16);
log("v:  " + v);
var hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(JSON.stringify(signed.msg)).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
log("hash:  " + hash);
return (v == hash);
}
```

I know the values I'm giving should result in a pass but now the logs are saying v = 1 whereas hash is (I would assume) what it should be.

Comment: Math.pow() surely won't work with BigIntegers, right? I don't really know Javascript. Doesn't CryptoJS have high-level sign and verify primitives? If not, you should be looking for something like key.doPublic() to be used in the verify operation. Also, you can't do verification with a *new* RSA key, you have use the public half of the *same* RSA keypair that was use to perform the signing.

Comment: @GregS That's kinda what I was thinking but I'm not sure how I would access it.  I have little knowledge of JS to begin with... The signed message comes in the format of type, msg, certname, sig and the public key comes in the format: type, n, e so I thought I'd have to create a new key using the values given in the two inputs for the function.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, I was parsing the n and e values to a wrong type.  The working code was:

```
function verify(pk, signed) {

var key = new RSAKey();
var s = JSON.stringify(signed.sig).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
s = new BigInteger(s, 16);
log("s:  " + s);
key.setPublic(pk.n, pk.e);
var v = key.doPublic(s).toString(16);
log("v:  " + v);
var hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(JSON.stringify(signed.msg)).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
log("hash:  " + hash);
return (v == hash);

}
```